# How to add External logic to BRMS rule engine?

Tags: drools, rule-engine, rule

How to add External logic to BRMS rule engine? For example I need to look for a word in sentence, i.e, Contains method. So how to add logic for Contains in BRMS?

Comment: You can use Java methods in constraints. - Show the rule you have so far, identifying the types of fact fields.

Comment: Hi laune , lets say i have to create a rule to find certain word in the given sentence i.e., Contains method , How to add this logic into BRMS?

Comment: What code do you have for running Drools?